# Graph of an ergoregion

Tags: plotting, numerics, physics

I'm trying to graph the region defined by the following equation (which comes from the $g_{00}$ element of the metric (2.1) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3927.pdf))

$$ g_{00}=-f H+H^{-1} \omega^2 r^2 \sin ^2 \theta $$

which in cylindrical coordinates and doing an inverse power series expansion of $z$, becomes

$$ g_{00}=\frac{16 B^6 q^2\left(z^2+2 m z\right) \rho^2}{16+8 B^2\left(\rho^2+3 q^2\right)+B^4\left(\rho^2+q^2\right)^2} $$

This equation is the one I want to graph and according to the article, I should get:

[image]

for $m = 1$, $B=1$ and $q = 1/2$. So what I did was code it in Mathematica like this:

```
g00 = (16*B^6*q^2*(z^2 + 2*m*z)*\[Rho]^2)/(
  16 + 8*B^2*(\[Rho]^2 + 3*q^2) + B^4*(\[Rho]^2 + q^2)^2);
m = 1; B = 1; q = 1/2;
DensityPlot[g00, {\[Rho], -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

However, I am not getting the graph from the article. Could someone please give me an observation or guidance?

Comment: Looks more like a `RegionPlot` to me. Isn't there any condition given in the paper?

Comment: @codebpr I didn't find any other conditions in the paper and when I use RegionPlot nothing is seen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the expanded form, but the full form of the metric component. Second, you want to plot a region, so you should use [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) instead of [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html). Third, I've forgot most of my general relativity course, so I am not sure what is the correct approach to calculate the ergoregion.

Here is my attempt:

$$\ell^2 = \ell^\mu \ell^\nu g_{\mu\nu} = g_{tt}+\Omega^2 g_{\phi\phi} -2\Omega g_{t\phi}.$$

```
toCylindrical[f_] := TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cylindrical", 
   f, {r, θ, ϕ} -> {ρ, ϕ2, z}];

f = 1 - (2 m)/r + q^2/r^2;
H = 1 + 1/2 B^2 (r^2 Sin[θ]^2 + 3 q^2 Cos[θ]^2) + 
    1/16 B^4 (r^2 Sin[θ]^2 + q^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2;
ω = -((2 q B)/r) + 1/2 q B^3 r (1 + f Cos[θ]^2);
ds = H (-f dt^2 + f^-1 dr^2 + r^2 dθ^2) + H^-1 r^2 Sin[θ]^2 (dϕ - ω dt)^2;

gtt = Coefficient[ds, dt^2] // Simplify;
gϕϕ = Coefficient[ds, dϕ^2] // Simplify;
gtϕ = Coefficient[ds, dt dϕ] // Simplify;

l = gtt + Ω^2 gϕϕ - 2 Ω gtϕ;

lcyl = toCylindrical[l];
gttcyl = toCylindrical[gtt];

params = {m -> 1, B -> 1, q -> 1/2, Ω -> 1};
RegionPlot[(gttcyl < 0 && lcyl > 0) /. params // Evaluate, 
  {ρ, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Two warnings: (1) I am using $\Omega = 1$ instead of $\Omega_H = 2 B q/\left(\sqrt{m^2-q^2}+m\right)-\frac{1}{2} B^3 q \left(\sqrt{m^2-q^2}+m\right) = 0.069$. If I use $\Omega_H$, I don't get any sensible ergoregion. (2) My region is not *completely* equivalent to the one in the article. Now either they used slightly smaller $\Omega$, or there is something wrong in my approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your partial response. It was really helpful to start understanding :)

Comment: @Dayzk, do you know how to correctly calculate the outer boundary of the ergoregion? I mean from the physical/mathematical perspective, not Mathematica. I haven't been able to figure it out from the article ...

Comment: @Dayzk, I have updated my answer, but the final plot is still not completely in agreement with the article. Please let me know if you determine a mistake in my approach :)